# ExpressJS backend to external server GET request fails on server deployment works fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, server, request, get

In my backend express js code I am trying to get information from another server and pass it along to the party that requested it. I have tried to use node-fetch axios http https. I have logged the request headers and tried the same operation on my Postman and localhost and everything works fine. But when deployed on a server to production the request fails. with a timeout. on localhost, this operation does not even take a second to complete. Sometimes when deployed repeatedly requesting the info to my backend from my frontend 14,15 times the response comes back PLEASE help, I have been stuck on this for days.